# Select all my and my friend friends except us both SQL

Tags: php

I have thee tables "user_follow", "images", "users"

My user_id : 3
My Friend user_id : 6

I need query to select all friends of me and my friend with their username and images
1) do not show us each other
2) duplicate friends show as 1

My query is :

```
    $sql = "SELECT u.username, i.image, u.id
            FROM users u
            LEFT JOIN user_follow f ON u.id = f.follow_id
            LEFT JOIN images i ON u.id = i.user_id
            WHERE f.user_id = 6 OR f.user_id = 3
            GROUP BY u.id
            ORDER BY f.date DESC";
```

and result is :

```
[user_both_follow] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [username] => Kolxoznik1
                [image] => 
                [id] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [username] => 7777
                [image] => 
                [id] => 8
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [username] => 6666
                [image] => flw3utn9igiqh7dtt2o61ydf8_174.jpeg
                [id] => 6
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [username] => 8888
                [image] => 
                [id] => 7
            )

    )
```

My query works at 50% it group the same friends but problem is that show my friend 3->6 (show)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the 'id' column for? IMHO the primary key should be (user_id,follow_id)..
A simple `AND f.follow_id != 3 and f.follow_id != 6` should fix your query.

Possibly simplified by:

```
WHERE f.user_id IN(3,6) AND f.follow_id NOT IN (3,6)
```

Also, you might want to `(RIGHT) JOIN user_follow` instead of left.

Also, maybe MySQL is smart enough to optimize this, but I wonder if `EXPLAIN` says something different for that query then for:

```
        SELECT u.username, i.image, u.id
        FROM user_follow f
        JOIN users u ON u.id = f.follow_id
        LEFT JOIN images i ON u.id = i.user_id
        WHERE f.user_id IN(3,6) AND f.follow_id NOT IN(3,6)
        GROUP BY u.id
        ORDER BY f.date DESC
```

Probably smart enough, but why keep the query planner guessing...