# Count data from table SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

my query:

```
           "SELECT id
            FROM user_follow
            WHERE user_id IN(3,6) AND follow_id NOT IN(3,6)
            GROUP BY follow_id";
```

and it show :

```
[users] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 19
            )

    )
```

I need to count data (in this example query must give back 3 as result)

---

I tried COUNT(id) but result was not good for me.

result :

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [count(id)] => 1
            )
```

I tried SELECT count(1)

result :

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [count(1)] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [count(1)] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [count(1)] => 1
            )
```

Still not not one number (3). I want something like this [users] => 3

Comment: What do you mean by the "result was not good"? Did you get an error? Was not the correct number?

Comment: Drop the `GROUP BY` then.... and just `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)`

Comment: I can't drop GROUP BY follow_id because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049401/select-all-my-and-my-friend-friends-except-us-both-sql this group prevent of showing the duplicate friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only the number and not the data itself you can try this:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM user_follow
WHERE user_id IN(3,6) AND follow_id NOT IN(3,6)
GROUP BY follow_id
```

Comment: I want to get back only one number (for example 3)

Comment: I tried your query, do not show one number. result is something like count(id)

Comment: I have post example with SELECT count(1)

Comment: your link http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php help me ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

you can try this

Answer (score 1):

if I am understanding your need, you can use count on the array itself as follows :

```
                $count=count($users)
```